# Execute a Shortcut in Command Prompt by Typing Only the Name

Tags: windows, command-line

If I have an executable file called "test.exe", in Command Prompt, the following command will invoke it:

**test**

However, if I have a *shortcut* to that same execute elsewhere called "test.lnk", just typing "test" in Command Prompt doesn't work. Instead I have to type:

**test.lnk**

Is there any way for me make test.lnk execute by just typing "test" in Command Prompt?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

for a permanent change you may use this commands:

**user-wide** (*for current user*):

```
setx pathext %pathext%;.lnk
```

**system-wide** (*for all users on the **m**achine*):

```
setx /m pathext %pathext%;.lnk
```

`setx` makes environment variable instead of session variable, which exists only in the `cmd.exe` process where it is set

another solution is to use `mklink` to create symlink (symbolic link) instead of shortcuts

eg:

```
mklink test.exe "c:\program files\application\test.exe"
```

symlinks don't have `.lnk` extension and size

ps:

after using the above mentioned `setx` commands you can find your variables here in the **environment variables** window which can be displayed using this command:

```
rundll32 sysdm.cpl,EditEnvironmentVariables
```

pps:

unlike `set`, [`setx`](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc755104.aspx) is an external command, ie an executable file, which is located at `c:\windows\system32` folder by default, and thus may not exist in some versions or editions of windows

Answer (score 1):

Add ;.LNK to the end of env var `PATHEXT`. For a single instance of CMD, you can just `SET PATHEXT=%PATHEXT%;.LNK`.

For a permanent change (all CMD going forward), find Advanced System Properties or Advanced System Settings, which occurs in different places on different Windows versions, click `Environment Variables` and look under `System Variables` (the bottom half).